# WooCommerce: Adding a second email address to a completed order

Tags: php, wordpress, email

As you know, WooCommerce doesn't have any options to add a second email adress in the mail settings for completed orders. Only customers are receiving these email. I don't mean the email that is sending, when everybody orderes something, I mean the mail, that is sending, when a order is completed by the admin in the backend.

The reason why I need this: The supplier of our shop need to be informed, when a order is completed by us, so that they can send out the ordered products. I found some solutions, but the most doesn't work anymore or where sending when a order is given, but as I said, I need this mail for completed orders.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put the following in your functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order', 'your_email_recipient_filter_function', 10, 2);

function your_email_recipient_filter_function($recipient, $object) {
    $recipient = $recipient . ', me@myemail.com';
    return $recipient;
}
```

> the only drawback is that the recipient will see both your address &
>   his own in the To: field.
>
> Alternatively, building on Steve's answer, you can use the
>   woocommerce_email_headers filter. the $object passed allows you to
>   only apply this to the completed order email:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'mycustom_headers_filter_function', 10, 2);

function mycustom_headers_filter_function( $headers, $object ) {
    if ($object == 'customer_completed_order') {
        $headers .= 'BCC: My name <my@email.com>' . "\r\n";
    }

    return $headers;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I also found this solution on stack and tried it yesterday, but doesn't work... now it works... maybe a mailserver problem.